# Playing card flip working on Github but not on Codepen or jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css

In my Web Foundations class, we learned about 3d transforms using CSS by making a playing card that shows the front of the playing card and then, when you click on it, would flip over and show the back, then flip to the front when clicking again. Worked fine. Here is my Github link for it:
https://dtarvin.github.io/3d/index.html
(Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.)

Yesterday I was working on having an image spin around and show another image. I started with the code for this and modified it in Codepen, but I didn't touch the Github code, only copied and pasted it. Before I modified anything, the playing card flip worked in Codepen. Once I modified it, I had my image spinner working, but I wanted to do more with it. I asked for help on here, and after modifying some code again, the spinner wasn't working right. So I tried to go back to the code I had when the spinner wasn't working, but I couldn't get it to work again.

This morning I decided to start over, so I copied my Github code into a new Codepen file. Exact same code (I went line by line and verified). But it's not working the same way in Codepen as it works in Github and is supposed to work. When you click on the card, it flips over, but instead of showing the back of the card, it just shows a reverse image of the front. Here is the Codepen link:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/EmbPqr)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="card">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

#container{
  width: 55vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 3000px;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 20vw;
}

#card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 2s;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

#card.flipped{
  transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(180deg);
}

#card div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front{
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/f1/db/2c/f1db2cddb90fd324cc32cefe1fa066d3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.back{
  background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_1AgA_BSRr40/TI_YtyvDrnI/AAAAAAAAAkA/MLMj23dgqtM/s1600/hoyleback.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

$("#card").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("flipped");
        });
```

I tried it in jsfiddle, copying the code directly from Github, and got the same thing. Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtarvin/0rynwkwa/

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="card">
            <div class="front">1</div>
            <div class="back">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

#container{
            width: 55vmin;
            height: 80vmin;
            position: relative;
            perspective: 3000px;
            top: 20vh;
            left: 20vw;
        }

        #card{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: all 2s;
            transform-origin: right top;
        }

        #card.flipped{
            transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(180deg);
        }

        #card div{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .front{
            background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/f1/db/2c/f1db2cddb90fd324cc32cefe1fa066d3.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .back{
            background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_1AgA_BSRr40/TI_YtyvDrnI/AAAAAAAAAkA/MLMj23dgqtM/s1600/hoyleback.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

$("#card").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("flipped");
        });
```

Why is the playing card working on Github and worked yesterday in Codepen but doesn't work today in Codepen and doesn't work in jsfiddle?

Comment: Something is obviously not the same. Asking us to go through multiple versions to figure out differences is far too broad a question

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just confirmed that the problem is not the code but the browser. I have a Mac and was using Safari. The Codepen and jsfiddle work in Chrome.